# Video in html page is not playing on mobile devices

Tags: html

I have the following tag

```html
<a id='bgndVideo' class='player' 
 data-property="{videoURL:'https://youtu.be/8ow9Y_QuFzE',
 containment:'#intro',showControls: false,autoPlay:true, mute:true, startAt:0, opacity:1}">Video not 
 supported 
</a>
```

This works fine in desktop browser plus when you toggle devices in browser toolbar. But in actual mobile browser ( Checked in both android and iOS mobiles) video is not playing. It will work on mobile browser if you set it to "desktop site" but by default it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `<video>` tag instead of `<a>`?

```
<video src="https://youtu.be/8ow9Y_QuFzE" autoplay>
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```